# How can I detect the location of Qt5 core in a CMake file on OS X?

Tags: cmake, qt5

I am using CMake to build a Qt5 project on OS X. I need to create a build process that is as simple as possible for others.

By default Qt5 installs to the home folder on OS X. However, it then places its files within a directory named after the exact version number, e.g. 5.2.1.

At the moment I am using these lines in my CMake file:

```
set(QT5_PATH $ENV{HOME}/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/ CACHE PATH "Path to Qt5")
set(QT5_MODULE_PATH ${QT5_PATH}/lib/cmake)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} ${QT5_MODULE_PATH})
```

This works, but unfortunately breaks with each minor update of Qt as the `5.2.1` needs to be changed to `5.2.2`, etc.

In Windows there are environment variables that can be used to find Qt. Is there anything similar in OS X that I can use within CMake to find a Qt installation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_package` instead of juggling with the paths yourself. Then your users can rely on standard CMake mechanism instead of figuring out your own CMake code.

Use `find_package(Qt5Widgets)` to get targets like `Qt::Widgets` to link against and for the includes.
Similar for `Qt5Core` and whatever part of Qt 5 you need.

See Qt's documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

Comment: Note that the documentation you link to does not recommend using `Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS` etc, but recommends imported targets like `Qt5::Widgets` instead. And you should recommend that too :).

Comment: @steveire You are right, I added an according sentence.

Comment: I should have said 'you should recommend that instead' (that is the article recommends it and you should too - not you should recommend the variables in addition - that doesn't make any sense). I see no reason to encourage anyone towards the variables. Use the imported targets and ignore the variables.